# Toggle class between two buttons in Angular2

Tags: html, button, angular5, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I am using angular 2 and I have two buttons I want toggle class between two buttons but. Below is my code

```
<button class="btn rounded" [ngClass]="{'btn-default': !clicked, 'btn-primary': clicked}" (click)="clicked = !clicked">
                                    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn rounded" [ngClass]="{'btn-default': !clicked, 'btn-primary': clicked}" (click)="clicked = !clicked">
                                    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
                                </button>
```

My problem is I want to toggle class but at time only one button can select and other condition is both buttons can be deselect. On click of one button other button should be deselect and once you click on selected button that button should be deselect and I want to do this only using buttons. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern which will work for any number of buttons:

In your controller, set up an array of buttons and a `selectedButton` variable

```
buttons= [
  {class: "fa fa-long-arrow-up", name: "button1"},
  {class: "fa fa-long-arrow-down", name: "button2"},
]
selectedButton;
toggleSelect(button) {
    if (button == this.selectedButton) {
        this.selectedButton = undefined
    } else {
        this.selectedButton = button
    }
}
```

Then in your template populate the `selectedButton` on click, and set your class based on whether it is selected

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons" class="btn rounded" [ngClass]="(selectedButton == button) ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default'" (click)="toggleSelect(button)">
    <i [class]="button.class"></i>
</button>
```

This way you could have any number of buttons and only one will ever be "selected" at a time

working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9zlaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks.. This is working but how can I deselect selected one button. Can you please help me

Comment: Want to select one button at time but both can be deselected

Comment: I have updated it to deselect the button if you click on it when it has already been selected